# Getting profile information twice displayed after query

Tags: django

my problem is when i try to display the profile information of a certain user i get displayed the information multiple times according to the number of created posts by the certain user. I dont know how change my query to get the profile information of an user once when i click on its name.

I created a get_context_data method but i dont know how to change the query to get the user information.

views.py

```py
class ProfilPostView(ListView):
   model=Post
   template_name='profile.html'

   #display posts created by user
   def get_queryset(self):

       return Post.objects.filter(author__username=self.kwargs['slug']).order_by('created_on')
       #return Post.objects.filter(author=self.request.user).order_by('created_on')

   #display profile information of user
   def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
       context=super(ProfilPostView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
       context['profiles']=Post.objects.filter(author__username=self.kwargs['slug'])
       return context




profile.html


                   <h3 style="padding-left:40%" class="lead">Name: {{ profiles.first_name}} {{profiles.last_name}}</h3>
               <p class="text-muted" style="padding-left:40%">Created: {{profiles.created_time.day}}.{{profiles.created_time.month}}.{{profiles.created_time.year}}</p>
               <p class="text-muted" style="padding-left:40% ">Email: {{profiles.email}}</p>


**UPDATE**
the code that displays the profile informations multiple times is the below one. the upper code is the one i changed for get_context_data method


           {% for post in object_list%}
               <h3 style="padding-left:40%" class="lead">Name: {{ post.author.first_name}} {{post.author.last_name}}</h3>
               <p class="text-muted" style="padding-left:40%">Created: {{post.author.created_time.day}}.{{post.author.created_time.month}}.{{post.author.created_time.year}}</p>
               <p class="text-muted" style="padding-left:40% ">Email: {{post.author.email}}</p>
           {% endfor %}
```

Comment: That code does not show anything multiple times. Do you have some kind of for loop somewhere? Show the rest of the template.

Comment: see the updated comment. i changed the post.html to see if my get_context_data is working.

Answer (score 1):

Since you care about a single Profile, I'm not sure why you are using a view that returns a list of Posts. You should use a DetailView based on Profile.

Your view should then just be (no need to override any methods at all):

```
class ProfilPostView(DetailView):
   model = Profil     # or whatever your profile model is called
   template_name = 'profile.html'
   slug_field = 'username'
```

And your template becomes:

```
   <h3 style="padding-left:40%" class="lead">Name: {{ object.first_name }} {{ object.last_name }}</h3>
   <p class="text-muted" style="padding-left:40%">Created: {{object.created_time.day}}.{{object.created_time.month}}.{{object.created_time.year}}</p>
   <p class="text-muted" style="padding-left:40% ">Email: {{object.email}}</p>
```

Comment: I think you meant to subclass `DetailView`, not `ListView`

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion. the problem is that i also want to display all the posts created by an user on his profile page thats why i used a listview instead of detailview.